# Gradio - How to retrieve DataFrame header in event listener method

Tags: python, dataframe, gradio

I have multiple DataFrames generated dynamically with a for loop, hence they all call the same event listener function (on input). Each DataFrame has only 1 column.
In this event listener function I need to know which DataFrame is passed as argument. The DataFrame argument is just the list of values.

Ideally I would like to get the header in the event listener function, but the DataFrame object just has a list of values.

The workaround I'm using now is to pass an additional component in inputs argument, a Label which contains the DataFrame name. But it's not really clean solution, for instance I have to make this label not visible.

Any idea how to do that? Hopefully there is something obvious that I don't know as I'm just starting to implement with Gradio.

Current code:
Part which generate the DataFrames:

```
for key, values in mylist.items():
  with gr.Accordion(label=key, open=False):
    df = gr.DataFrame(value=values, headers=[key], col_count=(1, "fixed"), type="array", interactive=True, wrap=True)
    df.input(fn=self.onDfInput, inputs=[gr.Label(key, visible=False), df], trigger_mode="once", concurrency_limit=1)
```

Event listener function:

```
def onDfInput(self, key: gr.Label, df: gr.DataFrame):
  print(key) # It works, return the DataFrame key
  print(df) # Only prints values, I don't see the headers
```